# Slickgrid v2.1 bug

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

On Slickgrid *example7-events.html*

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example7-events.html

if one changes the value of a cell on column Title and then **immediately** clicks on the Priority cell of the **same row**, the value of the cell on column Title looses the changes that were made, returning to its previous value. For example, on row 1, if we change the value of the Title cell from "Task 0" to "Whatever" and then immediately click on the corresponding Priority cell, changing its value to "High", the value of the Title cell annoyingly returns to "Task 0". But if we, instead of clicking in row 1 Priority cell, click on any other row's Priority cell, the value of the Title cell of the first row keeps the value "Whatever" as it should.

I'm using Slickgrid on a personal project and I also have this problem, but my onClick subscribe method is quite similar to the one on the example. So, the following questions raises: is this really a Slickgrid 2.1 bug, or is it a bug of *example7-events.html*? Does anyone has encountered this problem and somehow fixed it or found a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opening an issue on SlickGrid's project on GitHub and it was the example that was defective, not the framework. Here is the issue: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/496.

Best regards